# ExcelDNA RTD not updating new values unless changed manually

Tags: c#, xml, excel, excel-dna, rtd

I am using the cookie-cutter excelDNA solution named `TestRTD.dna` in `...\Dsitrbution\Samples\RTD\`.

I augmented `GetEurOnd()` to:

```
  public static object getTestObject(String arg){
    return GetTestItem(arg);
  }
```

Where `GetTestItem()` is unchanged.

My XML is of the following format:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <ISIN>
              <US05574LFY92>
                <ID_ISIN>US05574LFY92</ID_ISIN>
                <A>40</A>
                <B>100.089004516602</B>
                <C>11:22:48.000</C>
              </US05574LFY92>
            </ISIN>
```

So my formula looks like this in excel:

`=getTestObject("ISIN/US002799AM62/A")`

Which returns `40`. Great!

Now, I am running code throughout the day that is going to update the values in the xml using the following method:

```
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(recordPath))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("ISIN");

                foreach (rtTrace.dataObj d in lines)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement(d.ID_ISIN);

                    writer.WriteElementString("ID_ISIN", d.ID_ISIN);


                    writer.WriteElementString("A", d.A);
                    writer.WriteElementString("B", d.B);
                    writer.WriteElementString("C", d.C);


                    if (!tmp.ContainsKey(d.ID_ISIN))
                    {
                        tmp.Add(d.ID_ISIN, "");
                    }

                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }
```

Which successfully **DOES** update the values in my XML file, **yet the formula in excel still shows the old value**.

If I go in to my XML file and update the value **MANUALLY then the new value with flow through into excel**.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Hitting a wall.

Comment: If you put the formula into Excel after updating the file using your XmlWriter code, does it then show the correct result?

Comment: To check that the timer driving the RTD updates is running correctly, you might add a `DateTime.Now` string to the result.

Comment: @Govert No after updating the C# code, the correct result is not shown. That is the exact problem. I had the `DateTime.Now` but removed it once it was working manually.

Comment: Could it be that the resulting xml file no longer matches the `SelectSingleNode` selector in that example?

Comment: The nodes are actually identical every time. `<ISIN><US..etc><A></A>..etc`

Comment: Is this the proper way to modify the XML in C# such that it is registered in the excelDNA framework? Is there something at the granular file level that it is not properly "released" by the C# code, but is properly released by the manual update in notepad++?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Excel-DNA. You might like to extract all the xml parts into a separate sample and question.